# Airflow use execution date: 'datetime' is undefined

Tags: python, airflow

I want to use the execution time in Airflow and add one day to it:

```
'{{(execution_date + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}'
```

When I execute this I get

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'timedelta' is undefined
```

How can I get the execution time plus one day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://diogoalexandrefranco.github.io/about-airflow-date-macros-ds-and-execution-date/

You can use:

```
'{{(execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}'
```

The macros object exposes common python functions and libraries like macros.datetime and macros.timedelta

Comment: @jpp I wanted to share my solution to this problem but made a mistake in my copy paste. I edited it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
'{{(execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}'
```

Use macros to pass dynamic information into task instances at runtime.